# How to prroperly store & retrieve a number on a website using MySQL/otger data system

Tags: mysql, web

In an app I'm making I want to show a number.

Think of this as a subscribe button on Youtube. Whenever a user performs an action in the app, the number goes up one.

**How do I store, add to, and access this number?** People recommended MySQL or a simple text file.

What is the proper way to do this safely from an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a database point of view, these steps and accompanying SQL code will provide a starting point.  Take a look at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/%23!9/eeebd/2/0) to see a live demo of the code.

1. Create database table to store data
2. Create insert statement to add
   data to database
3. Create SQL query to retrieve information
4. Create SQL query to retrieve count of subscribers

*Explanation of fields*

- "id" field uniquely identifies each row. This is accomplished with
  the field being auto incremented.
- "subscriberID" field represents the Id of the user which clicked the
  subscribed button.
- "subscribed" field represents when the user clicked the subscribe
  button. This field is automatically populated with the date and time
  of when the button was clicked.

---

**Create database table to store data**

```
CREATE TABLE subscribers
( Id int not null auto_increment, 
subscriberID int,
subscribed datetime default current_timestamp,
primary key(id) );
```

**Create insert statement to add data to database**

```
Insert into subscribers (subscriberID) values (12345),(6789),(24536);
```

**Create SQL query to retrieve information**

```
Select subscriberid, subscribed
From subscribers;
```

**Create SQL query to retrieve count of subscribers**

```
Select count(*) as "Total Number of Subscribers"
From subscribers;
```

Comment: Hi @Jaxswat if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.